# How to add external link to XML document (DTD shema)?

Tags: xml, syntax-error, dtd

Firstly - create `xml` file `contract01.xml` and add some common link - `&buyer;`.

With this aim is another file `contr01.dtd`. Which is created according DTD Sheme.

And need to change link from `&buyer;` to `Vasul Vadultsyv`

But when launch this `.xml` file at `Chrome` browser it shows next `errors:`

```
This page contains the following errors:

error on line 4 at column 17: Entity 'buyer' not defined
error on line 6 at column 24: Entity 'buyer' not defined
error on line 7 at column 35: Entity 'buyer' not defined
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.
```

I can't understant why this happen.
Have you some idea how to fix this situation with links into `XML(DTD)` at correct way.
I tryed this example from [Sams Teach Yourself XML in 21 Days (3rd Edition)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672325764).
Maybe this can be a little bit old information.

**Code (contract01.xml):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE contract SYSTEM "contr01.dtd">
<contract>
    <para1>&buyer; agrees to buy the property defined below on the terms 
            and conditions set forth in this contract.</para1>
    <para2 section="1">&buyer; will take title of the real propirty described below, 
            for which consideration &buyer; agrees to pay... </para2>
</contract>
```

**Code (contr01.dtd)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!ELEMENT contract (para1, para2)>
<!ELEMENT para1 (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT para2 (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST para2
    selection CDATA #REQUIRED>
<!ENTITY buyer "Vasul Vadultsyv">
```

**Question:**

- How do solve this trouble?
- Can you recomend some good xml tutorials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think chrome will load the DTD from your local system. Try including the entity declaration in the internal subset:

```
<!DOCTYPE contract SYSTEM "contr01.dtd" [
<!ENTITY buyer "Vasul Vadultsyv">
]>
```

Maybe you should try validating your XML with an actual validator instead of a web browser. ([Xerces](http://xerces.apache.org/) is easy to use.)

Comment: Thanks, this adding was successfull. Do you know some good XML tutorials?

Comment: @nazar_art - I don't really know of any good tutorials. Mulberry has great quick reference docs (http://www.mulberrytech.com/quickref/index.html). Other than that, the spec is the place I go if I have a question. http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/ and http://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/